# search without typing quotation marks

Tags: search, search-results, enterprise-search

Is it possible to search for the title of a document without placing any quotes around it?

Example, when a user searches with the title of a document like: Doc nr 123, gets no results back, but when user places quotes around the title "Doc nr 123", then results are displayed. How can we search without quotes as well?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes are used to specify a query for a phrase rather than the individual words of the query. In your case the challenge for the query is (probably) the numbers and that "nr" is not a word. Though I am just guessing.

What I have done in this case is create a Query Rule that adds the quotes and applies it to the Title property, for example `Title:"{searchterms}"`. Another alternative is to use RegEx to detect the pattern f your document titles and apply the query rule that way, though that only works on-premises.